# Separation of JUnit classes into special test package?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am learning the concepts of Test-Driven Development through reading the [Craftsman articles](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/publishedArticles.html) (click *Craftsman* under *By Topic*) recommended in an answer to my previous question, ["Sample project for learning JUnit and proper software engineering"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376975/sample-project-for-learning-junit-and-proper-software-engineering). I love it so far!

But now I want to sit down and try it myself. I have a question that I hope will need only a simple answer.

**How do you organize your JUnit test classes and your actual code?** I'm talking mainly about the package structure, but any other concepts of note would be helpful too.

Do you put test classes in org.myname.project.test.* and normal code in org.myname.project.*? Do you put the test classes right alongside the normal classes? Do you prefer to prefix the class names with Test rather than suffix them?

I know this seems like the kind of thing I shouldn't worry about so soon, but I am a very organization-centric person. I'm *almost* the kind of person that spends more time figuring out methods to keep track of what to get done, rather than actually getting things done.

And I have a project that is currently neatly divided up into packages, but the project became a mess. Instead of trying to refactor everything and write tests, I want to start fresh, tests first and all. But first I need to know where my tests go.

---

*edit:* I totally forgot about Maven, but it seems a majority of you are using it! In the past I had a specific use case where Maven completely broke down on me but Ant gave me the flexibility I needed, so I ended up attached to Ant, but I'm thinking maybe I was just taking the wrong approach. I think I'll give Maven another try because it sounds like it will go well with test-driven development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should I put my JUnit tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811827/where-should-i-put-my-junit-tests)

Answer (score 165, accepted):

I prefer putting the test classes into the same package as the project classes they test, but in a different physical directory, like:

```
myproject/src/com/foo/Bar.java
myproject/test/com/foo/BarTest.java
```

In a Maven project it would look like this:

```
myproject/src/main/java/com/foo/Bar.java
myproject/src/test/java/com/foo/BarTest.java
```

The main point in this is that my test classes can access (and test!) package-scope classes and members.

As the above example shows, my test classes have the name of the tested class plus `Test` as a suffix. This helps finding them quickly - it's not very funny to try searching among a couple of hundred test classes, each of whose name starts with `Test`...

**Update** inspired by @Ricket's comment: this way test classes (typically) show up right after their tested buddy in a project-wise alphabetic listing of class names. (Funny that I am benefiting from this day by day, without having consciously realized how...)

**Update2:** A lot of developers (including myself) like Maven, but there seems to be at least as many who don't. IMHO it is very useful for "mainstream" Java projects (I would put about 90% of projects into this category... but the other 10% is still a sizeable minority). It is easy to use if one can accept the Maven conventions; however if not, it makes life a miserable struggle. Maven seems to be difficult to comprehend for many people socialized on Ant, as it apparently requires a very different way of thinking. (Myself, having never used Ant, can't compare the two.) One thing is for sure: it makes unit (and integration) testing a natural, first-class step in the process, which helps developers adopt this essential practice.

Comment: I agree with the suffix note too. Also since the test classes are separated into a different physical folder, there's no need to try and prefix with Test in some attempt to trick an alphabetical order sort into grouping, and I think SomeClassTest reads better.

Comment: One thing about putting test classes in the same package: while it allows to use package-private members (which why I use this scheme too), it also doesn't allow to test visibility automatically, esp. if you use TDD and let your IDE generate needed method stubs. It may generate them with package-private visibility (NetBeans, I'm looking at you), which makes your test pass perfectly (after you actually put implementation into that stubs), but may fail in real use (if you forgot to add `public`).

Comment: While this convention is interesting, what do you do when the test suite grows? E.g. let's say you have 6 methods in the class, each method has 10 tests. Do you have 60 tests in your class? I usually subdivide the test class (one test class per method). The problem with this is that you might find a lot of classes in your test package.

Comment: How can this be done in Eclipse? All I can seem to accomplish is two different packages, myproject\src... and myproject\test... How do you add content from multiple directories to a single package?

Comment: @Thick_propheT in Eclipse: right click on the project name, click New - Other..., then inside the Java folder select Source Folder. name it "test". Then if you wnat to follow the convention above, add a new package to this test folder having the same name as the package of the class for which you want to write test case, then in the package add a new JUnit Test Case (located in the Java/Junit folder when you do New-Other...). in that new wizard you can specify the class being tested and name your test case as the same name with "Test" suffix

Answer (score 17):

I put my test classes in the same package as what they are testing **but in a different source folder or project**.  Organizing my test code in this fashion allows me to easily compile and package it separately so that production jar files do not contain test code.  It also allows the test code to access package private fields and methods.

Answer (score 14):

I use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). The structure that Maven promotes is:-

```
src/main/java/org/myname/project/MyClass.java

src/test/java/org/myname/project/TestMyClass.java
```

i.e. a test class with Test prepended to the name of the class under test is in a parallel directory structure to the main test.

One advantage of having the test classes in the same package (not necessarily directory though) is you can leverage package-scope methods to inspect or inject mock test objects.

Comment: I though it was `<class>Test.java`, not `Test<class>.java`

Comment: Maven will accept either pattern, as per [the Maven Surefire Plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

Comment: I'd argue that the `<class>Test.java` naming scheme makes both the main class and test class show up close when using IDE search features, which makes it a bit better than `Test<class>.java`.

Comment: @christopheml I agree, that's what I do now.

Comment: This worked for Intellij. MyClassTest.java did not work.