# How to structure JUnit test directory outside of main package?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit5

I have the following directory and packages using Eclipse and I need to make unit tests on it.

[image: Directory]

I've tried a few organizations but they always fail, or don't find the classes to work. When I google how to do it, I always get some vague references to Maven, which I do not know what it is.

**Is there a way to move *test classes* out from main package** (in screenshot:`UnitTests.java`), so it can still be run, but be more *organized*?

Comment: Maven is a tool for building/packaging your application - it's very commonly used in Java so if you are planning to work in that language it might be useful to learn the basics of it.  Anyhow, most of the time, you can create a `test` folder (next to `src`) and have all your test files organized there.

Comment: you have to use `maven`, maven provides a standard directory structure for test classes and non test classes.

Comment: @JobinJoseph OP does not ***have to*** use maven - but it will be very helpful as, like you stated, it provides a standard directory structure and approach for these type of things

Comment: How do I convert this to maven? Or use it for this project? That or how do I organize it within the test folder?

Comment: To convert to maven, first do a simple reorganization to follow the [maven standard directory structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), and move your tests to the separate test folder. After that, create a `pom.xml` file, for example via Eclipse -- see the question on [converting an existing Eclipse project to maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449461/convert-existing-eclipse-project-to-maven-project). Then you can use `mvn` from the command line (or Eclipse) to compile, test, and release your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can declare another Java package in your project (for example: `unittests.com.oop.*` and move your test classes in it.

You'll then have `com.oop.*` containing main classes, and `unittests.com.oop.*` containing associated unittests.

In long see [possible duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388253/separation-of-junit-classes-into-special-test-package)

Comment: That comes as a workaround at best, and normally is the wrong thing to do. Such a change comes in hand with setbacks, for instance protected variables become automatically inaccessible. Eclipse can't do this by default, and this must be mentioned in first place. IntelliJ IDEA handles this differently. It puts tests in completely different folder, and after compile the tests also goes to different location. Other than that, good answers are provided in the possible duplicate. When you organize the project as Maven, then eclipse is able to handle it correctly.